# How to match "mut" in a Rust macro?

Tags: macros, rust, token

I would like to pass mutability to a macro so that I can do

```
mymacro![mut foo];
mymacro![bar];
```

and the macro will see them as different matches. which specifier to use?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one.  You'll need two rules: one which matches a literal `mut`, and one that doesn't.

```
macro_rules! do_something {
    (mut $name:ident) => { ... };
    ($name:ident) => { ... };
}
```

And yes, they *do* have to be in that order, because macro arms are matched top-to-bottom.

Comment: Is it still the case that they have to be in that order? I have been testing a macro where the rules are in the opposite order and haven't observed any difference.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock No, it would only matter if the macro could match both arms at the same time, in which case the top one would be chosen. In this case, since `mut` can't be an `ident`, there should be no difference.